# Umbraco and MVC and JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

So I got pulled into a deep end having zero experience in umbraco and a tight deadline. 
I don't know how umbraco works and how you integrate your MVC site into it really. A lot of headfuzz to get around.

basically the person I am inheriting it from created a basic controller from MVC and we can call the MVC site as we normally do.

I can also do JSON calls to the controller action which gives us back some data in a ViewModel. Great.
But when you browse to the site using umbraco and navigate to that same page, we run into big problems such as not being able to invoke the JSON call to get the data as it says object not found (in other words, the controller action is not found).

I read about umbraco basically overriding the default MVC routings but... why such a mess? :)

how can I integrate an existing MVC site into umbraco without much pain?
what is the url to call a controller action in umbraco integration?

say we have this:

```
public JsonResult GetPersonDetail(int id)
{
   var vm = new AjaxPersonDetailViewModel(....);
   return new JsonResult( Data = vm };
}
```

I can call this in JQuery like so:

/MyController/GetPersonDetail/1

so how do I do that with Umbraco?

Comment: One way of doing it would be to extend your controller from SurfaceController and you call your actions like /umbraco/surface/mycontroller/getpersondetail/1

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I think I did try this but still got an error saying object not found. I'm going to try with a clean project and setup my demo environment with umbraco and do it step by step here to see if it will work. its one of those projects where the people have mishmashed things together

Answer (score 0):

Also try using this scaffolding package as well to get the initial bits for your controller in the right place http://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Mvc/scaffolding.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate this and will try it shortly. Is there a way i can create my MVCs in VS without using the nugut package?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just manually create the files that the scaffolding process creates and reference them accordingly however i prefer to use that first then add/tweak the auto files to match what i need

Comment: So, the problem seemed to have been the way the project was. the guys were creating 2 projects. one was a proper ASP.NET MVC 4 web project and the other was an umbraco website project. They were mixing it up together which made it all weird. There were things that just didn't work so now I have cleaned it up and only using the umbraco project and creating controllers deriving from the SurfaceController. I can now do things like callouts from AJAX to the controller.